# thread synchronization: making sure function gets called in order

Tags: multithreading, synchronization

I'm writing a program in which I need to make sure a particular function is called is not being executed in more than one thread at a time.

Here I've written some simplified pseudocode that does exactly what is done in my real program.

```
mutex _enqueue_mutex;
mutex _action_mutex;
queue _queue;
bool  _executing_queue;

// called in multiple threads, possibly simultaneously
do_action() {
  _enqueue_mutex.lock()
  object o;
  _queue.enqueue(o);
  _enqueue_mutex.unlock();

  execute_queue();
}

execute_queue() {
  if (!executing_queue) {
    _executing_queue = true;
    enqueue_mutex.lock();
    bool is_empty = _queue.isEmpty();
    _enqueue_mutex.lock();
    while (!is_empty) {
      _action_mutex.lock();

      _enqueue_mutex.lock();
      object o = _queue.dequeue();
      is_empty = _queue.isEmpty();
      _enqueue_mutex.unlock();

      // callback is called when "o" is done being used by "do_stuff_to_object_with_callback" also, this function doesn't block, it is executed on its own thread (hence the need for the callback to know when it's done)
      do_stuff_to_object_with_callback(o, &some_callback);
    }
    _executing_queue = false;
  }
}

some_callback() {
  _action_mutex.unlock();
}
```

Essentially, the idea is that `_action_mutex` is locked in the while loop (I should say that `lock` is assumed to be blocking until it can be locked again), and expected to be unlocked when the completion callback is called (`some_callback` in the above code).

This, does not seem to be working though. What happens is if the `do_action` is called more than once at the same time, the program locks up. I think it might be related to the while loop executing more than once simultaneously, but I just cant see how that could be the case. Is there something wrong with my approach? Is there a better approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `queue` that is not specifically designed to be multithreaded (multi-producer multi-consumer) will need to serialize both `eneueue` and `dequeue` operations using the same mutex.

(If your `queue` implementation has a different assumption, please state it in your question.)

The check for `_queue.isEmpty()` will also need to be protected, if the `dequeue` operation is prone to the [*Time of check to time of use* problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).

That is, the line
`object o = _queue.dequeue();`
needs to be surrounded by `_enqueue_mutex.lock();` and `_enqueue_mutex.unlock();` as well.

Comment: oops... I have that in my code... I just missed it when I was typing out the pseudocode. I'll update my question. Thanks

Comment: The first step to debug a program is to add some `printf` statements.

Comment: Well please don't think me rude for saying this, but I did try to solve the issue on my own before asking for help. I know that the while loop tries to execute more than once (see question) because of this. Also, locking the mutex for checking isEmpty doesnt solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You probably only need a single mutex for the queue. Also once you've dequeued the object, you can probably process it outside of the lock. This will prevent calls to `do_action()` from hanging too long.

```
mutex moo;
queue qoo;
bool keepRunning = true;

do_action():
{
    moo.lock();
    qoo.enqueue(something);
    moo.unlock(); // really need try-finally to make sure,
    // but don't know which language we are using
}

process_queue():
{
    while(keepRunning)
    {
        moo.lock()
        if(!qoo.isEmpty)
            object o = qoo.dequeue();

        moo.unlock(); // again, try finally needed

        haveFunWith(o);
        sleep(50);
    }
}
```

Then Call `process_queue()` on it's own thread.

Comment: well the idea is that I can add to the queue as much as I want and make sure that `haveFunWith(o)` finishes executing in the same order as it started... so I should be able to add to the queue while some `o` is being played with. BTW, the language is C++ and i'm using Qt, which doesn't throw exceptions as far as i know.

Comment: Using this method things will all be started and finished in order. the queue is by nature ordered, and they are all being processed from a single thread (assuming haveFunWith() is synchronous).

Comment: "assuming haveFunWith() is synchronous" it occurs to me that I didn't mention it isn't... my bad

Comment: Should be easy enough to make it synchronous.
haveFunWith(o);
waitForFunToBeComplete();